# Compare values with a specific margin of error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, compare

Is there a way to compare two values of type `double` in PySpark, with a specified margin of error?
Essential similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933783/compare-values-allowing-for-a-specific-margin-of-error), but in PySpark.

Something like:

```
df=#some dataframe with 2 columns RESULT1 and RESULT2

df=withColumn('compare', when(col('RESULT1')==col('RESULT2') +/- 0.05*col('RESULT2'), lit("match")).otherwise(lit("no match"))
```

But in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `between` as the condition:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'compare',
    when(
        col('RESULT1').between(0.95*col('RESULT2'), 1.05*col('RESULT2')), 
        lit("match")
    ).otherwise(
        lit("no match")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write as `|RESULT1 - RESULT2| <= 0.05 * RESULT2` :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    'compare',
    F.when(
        F.abs(F.col('RESULT1') - F.col("RESULT2")) <= 0.05 * F.col("RESULT2"),
        F.lit("match")
    ).otherwise(F.lit("no match"))
)
```